# Json and rest-assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I’m new in rest assured and Java.
I need help ,
 I want to create a Json object ( Array Json with key , value ) that I can add / remove parameters , and  change the values . I need the Json to be generic & dynamic - I hope it make sense ...
After I want to call a get API and validate using rest assured that all the return keys and values in the response are present in the Json object I have created before .
Can anyone help understand how to start the solution for this ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to both RA and Java, may I suggest you evaluate [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) because in my opinion, it is far easier to do what you have described, for example look at this example [`cats.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/cats/cats.feature).

Karate allows you to also read JSON from a file and modify it. You can also modify responses and re-use them for future requests.

Disclaimer: am dev.